# Fetch information after svn's branch deleting

Tags: svn, branch, trunk

We had an svn branch an everybody committed there. Then one programmer deleted it and created it again by copying trunk. So, important commits have been deleted in that branch. Do we have any chances to restore the deleted information?

Comment: See the linked question. If you know a good revision number, you can restore it.

Comment: You can do it even if you don't remember the revision number BTW. Check the svn log.